# ODBC connection for testing Availability Group Listener

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I am having difficulty verifying my Availability Group Listener configuration.  I would like to create an ODBC connection which points to the listener.  When I configure the system DSN and try to test the connection at the end, I get timeout errors.  However, when I change the server to point to the instance name instead of the listener name, the connection works.  How can I test the listener using ODBC? What other method can I use to test the listener?

Note: I do not have access to an application to test client connectivity.

Comment: You can use `SQLCMD.exe -S <AG listener> -D <AG database> -E`. What port is your Listener configured to listen ? you may want to specify `AGlistener,port_no` to see if you can connect to the listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer :

You can use `SQLCMD.exe -S <AG listener> -D <AG database> -E`.

You may want to specify `AGlistener,port_no` to see if you can connect to the listener.